# How do I make a button switch to a new activity?

Tags: android

I am trying to start a new activity using a button, but the new activity only shows for about five seconds and comes back. This is what my code looks like:

```
public class Splash  extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
Button next, Previous, menu;
ViewFlipper vf;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    menu = (Button)findViewById(R.id.menu);
    Previous = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button02);
    vf = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.ViewFlipper1); 

    next.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
    Previous.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);

    menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
              Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, Menu.class);
              startActivity(intent);
         }
   });        
   }

   public void onClick(View v) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   if(v==next){
      vf.showNext();
   }
   if(v==Previous){
        vf.showPrevious();
   }  
 }
}
```

This is the code for the Menu activity. It's incomplete, though:

```
public class Menu extends AFFIRMATION implements OnClickListener{
Button about;
Button contact;
Button products;
Button cards;

//@override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);

    about = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    contact = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    products = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
     cards = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);



}


@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Comment: I think the question might be what is causing the Menu activity to stop / finish? Could you post the code for that Activity also? Does logcat show any errors from your app that might explain why Menu activity is ending?

Comment: and u describe more what u want? are u want to show activity in flipper??

Comment: something inappropriate in AFFIRMATION class

Comment: @mmeyer thanks for your response i have posted the code for the other activty and there are no errors in the logcat

Comment: @HemantMenaria the button is in the flipper and i want it to be starting a new activity called Menu

Comment: Can you add the code for the AFFIRMATION class you inherit Menu from? I still believe that activity is crashing and youre just not seeing it in logcat. Set the level to error and look for something from ActivityManager.

Answer (score 0):

Look at xml where you define your ViewFlipper. 
See if [`android:autoStart`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html#attr_android%3aautoStart) and [`android:flipInterval`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html#attr_android%3aflipInterval) have been set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
have u Declare the new Activity in your manifest.xml.
you have to write this in  between....

<application> ........


<activity android:name=".Menu"
                  android:label="xyz"/>


</application>
```

Comment: i have already declared the new activity in the manifest but the problem is still persisting